# Selecting K best features based on pearson r correlation coefficient

Tags: pandas, feature-selection

I am trying to select features for a linear model. I am required to select 15 most correlated features using the pearson r correlation coefficient.

Using the `selectKBest()`, I need to declare a callable function to be passed into it to determine the correlation for each column to my target value. I have declared the function as follows:

```
def scoring_function(x, y):
    for col in x:
        pearsonr(x[col], y)
```

I have checked to ensure that this function is callable by calling `callable()` on it. However, i still get a type error when calling sellectKBest stating that a `None` was passed instead of a `callable`. I am also not sure if this is the function that will help me achieve my desired outcome of finding the 15 most correlated features to my target value (`x` and `y` respectively in my function above)

Answer (score 0):

As from `SelectKBest` documentation from scikit-learn, the callable should return an array of scores.

```py
def scoring_function(X, y):
    scores = [pearsonr(X[col], y), for col in X.columns]
    return scores
```

I am assuming that `X` is a DataFrame, so it has column names.

I do not know the specifics of your project, but I suggest you take a look at [Factor Analysis](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/decomposition.html#fa) (also available in scikit-learn), which in my opinion is appropriate to what you want to accomplish.